# Portfolio optimization - problem with a proof

Tags: optimization, finance

I'm trying to proof Proposition 1 in [this Paper about Markowitz Portfolio Opitimization on page 6/7](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~nanasid/Computational-Physics/Material/Random%20Matrices/08-08.pdf) but I can't figure out how to do this. The author wrote "The proof of Proposition 1 can be found from many references in the literature", but I couldn't find it anywhere. Does anyone know where can I find the proof of this theorem? Or at least give some hint how to solve it (
From my research I suppose that I have to use conditional extremum Lagrange multipliers method but I don't know how)?